# What is the expected number of rounds that everyone get back their own ball?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Sppose there are $n$ people and each of them a unique ball. Suppose now they put the ball inside a box and the balls inside the box would then be mixed up. Then each of them will go out to draw a ball from the box.

Suppose that for each round , all people would draw a ball from the box. Those who draw their own balls can leave and the rest would go to the second rounds. What is the expected number of rounds that everyone get back their own ball?

Comment: Were you actually able to turn the accepted answer into a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*n*.

For each person the expected value is 1/n. The expected value for all n people is therefore 1, by linearity of expectation. If the expected value of each round is 1, then the expected value of n rounds is n.

Comment: Sorry, when i get deeper thought to the solution i get a little bit confused. Could you explain more about the part that once you find expected value of n people is 1 then you claim the expected round is n. Can it be Written in terms of the Random Variable? The reason i get confused is when finding the expected values of the number of rounds, it seems there could be infinite many so i dont quite get although it sounds true.

Comment: Ya, that's what i have thought but the $x$ can be infinity right? And if $x$ is infinity, i think the expression of the expection is kind of weird and i am not sure how the expression would be like

Comment: Two problems invalidate this answer (or rather, its explanation in the comments, the answer itself being rather cryptic): first, the question is not to solve for $x$ the equation $E[R_1+\cdots+R_x]=n$ but to compute $E[T]$ where $T=\inf\{x\mid R_1+\cdots+R_x=n\}$; second $E[R_i]\ne1$ (except when $i=1$) since $E[R_i]$ is the probability that round $i$ is needed, that is, the probability that the $i-1$ first rounds did not achieve that everybody gets back their own ball. Equivalently, $E[R_i]=P[T\geqslant i]$ hence $E[T]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty E[R_i]$.

Comment: @Did: Thanks very much. Of course I don't mean to be incorrect. Can you post a better answer please, as I cannot delete mine?

Comment: No hope that you correct yours? Since it got accepted, one could consider this is something you owe to the OP.

Comment: I don't completely understand how to go about calculating the infinite sum.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value comes out as $n$.

You can write a recurrence relation for the expected time it takes with $n$ people, $T_n$. Clearly, $T_0=0,\ T_1 = 1$. In general, if there are $n$ people, after the first round you have probability ${n \choose k} d_k/n!$ of exactly $k$ people remaining in the second round, where $d_k = k! \sum_{l\leq k}(-1)^l/l!$ is the number of permutations of $k$ elements with no fixed point. This leads to the recursive relation:
$$ T_n = \sum_{k\leq n} (T_k +1) {n \choose k} d_k/n!. $$
You can check by hand that $T_n = n$ for small $n$. If you can do this in general, then you have the solution to the problem. Ultimately, this can be reduced to showing that:
$$
\sum_{l \leq k \leq n} \frac{(k+1)(-1)^l}{(n-k)!l!} = n.
$$
This should be doable.

Comment: "This should be doable" Indeed it is, using for example the exponential generating function $\sum\limits_{k\geqslant0}\frac1{k!}d_kx^k=\mathrm e^{-x}(1-x)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Did: Thanks, this indeed seems to work! Should I incorporate this into the answer?